# Active Directory group not displayed in membership tab in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, active-directory

I recently activated My Site in my portal. I wanted to display the users that belonged to a particular distribution list in active directory.

I have created distribution list and also security group in active directory and added members to it. After doing a full synchronization i still do not see any list from active directory in the membership tab of My Site in SharePoint 2010. Could someone help me in this?

Comment: Did you add the distribution list or the security group?